# white-space: nowrap not working with floats - Can't fit star rating into my table cell

Tags: html, css, user-interface

This is a pure css question , I have a table with more than 13 columns. 
The table is fixed width, with each column set using a percent value (I am not sure if this is the best way to go about it )
I have a 5 star rating form in the table.
The issue is I would like it to fit into the table cell as a single in line element like this

```
****
```

but no matter what i do , it adjusts itself drastically into the table.
Here is the js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/q5rfy4ea/1/

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a combination that *sounds* right but doesn't work how you're expecting it to.

In `.rating:not(:checked) > label` you're setting a `float: right` property and then trying to force a `nowrap` scenario using `white-space: nowrap`.  Try changing the rule to look like this:

```
.rating:not(:checked) > label {
    display: inline-block; /* Go ahead and keep the rest the same */
    ...
}
```

## [Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5rfy4ea/9/)

Comment: Still if you hover you see it goes from right to left now.

Comment: @Stacked-for-life - Simple, reverse the order of the elements so that they progress normally instead of reversed.